# electron Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: angularjs, electron

I have simple problem but I can't seem to get the correct path right. everything seems to be OK, followed tutorial from [here](http://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/)

I have file structure like here.

```
.
├── Makefile
├── README.md
├── app
│   ├── electron.html
├── app.js
├── bower.json
├── bower_components
│   ├── Chart.js
```

I tried loading some local resources in `electron.html` my local resources

`<script src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>`

but..

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js
```

how do I load the local resources?
thanks to electron 1.0 btw. I wanted to try it out fast though..

Comment: Can you paste the contents of your app's entry javascript file (Where you create the Browser window)

Comment: hi, I think I just got it from the example. I copy and pasted it to [gist](https://gist.github.com/Hokutosei/d087354dd09593576dc0a05f51d02640)